# Distinct rows with in self Join output

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT c.dept as department, c.name as manager, d.name as name 
FROM COMPLEX c  
JOIN COMPLEX d ON d.Manager = c.ID
```

Using the above Self Join query I got this output

```
department  |   manager   | name
-------------------------------------
SW          |    Ranjan   | Deeksha

SW          |    Ranjan   | sham

SW          |    Ranjan   | Junaid

HQ          |    Vinay    | akhilesh

HQ          |    Vinay    | Pranav
```

But I need the Final output as:

```
department  |   manager  | name
------------------------------------
SW          |    Ranjan  | Deeksha

            |            | sham

            |            | Junaid

HQ          |    Vinay   | akhilesh

            |            | Pranav
```

Comment: This is what outer joins are for.

Comment: Use something like Excel or SQL server reporting services to accomplish this. You may be able to do this in T-SQL but it is not going to be pretty because you have to force SQL to behave the way it is not supposed to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
NAME, CASE 
WHEN seq > 1 THEN ''
ELSE manager END AS Manager,
CASE 
WHEN seq > 1 THEN '' 
ELSE dept END AS dept 
FROM (SELECT b.NAME,b.dept,a.NAME AS manager, 
Row_number()OVER(partition BY a.dept ORDER BY a.dept DESC) seq 
FROM   complex a 
JOIN complex b ON a.id = b.manager) d
```

Comment: Please format your code and add little explanation to your answer.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question